# Spark - need to Raise exception from UDF and terminate OR need to access values in spark withColumn function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am calling an API using withColumn and I want to throw an exception and exit the run when I get an exception status codes from API.

I have implemented using UDF and every thing is working fine but I am not able throw an exception from UDF.
I have to  process the entire rows and return the response from API for each row, and check if any failure occurs by filter and then terminate the job.
UDF
`

```
val postApiCall = udf((json: Seq[String], postApiUrl : String, entityName: String, apiKey: String,
                                              batchRunId: String, dictionaryVersion: String) => {

    logger.info(s"######### Executing postApiCall with apiKey: $apiKey, batchRunId: $batchRunId #########")
    val requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString
    val apiCallLoop = new Breaks
    try {
      // create an HttpPost object
      val url =  s"$postApiUrl/$entityName"
      val timeout = 1800
      val requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000).build()
      val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build()
      val post: HttpPost = new HttpPost(url)

      val entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("data", "[" + json.mkString(",") + "]", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("apiKey", apiKey)
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("batchRunId", batchRunId)
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("mode", "NORMAL")
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("dataFormat", "JSON")
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("requestId", requestId)
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("dictionaryVersion", dictionaryVersion)
      entityBuilder.setCharset(Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()))
      //val httpEntity = new GzipCompressingEntity(entityBuilder.build())
      val httpEntity = entityBuilder.build()
      post.setEntity(httpEntity)
      var response: CloseableHttpResponse = client.execute(post)
      //500 - INTERNAL_FAILURE, 503 - SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
      if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode == HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ||
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode == HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
        apiCallLoop.breakable {
          for (i <- 1 to 5) {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            response = client.execute(post)
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode != HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR &&
              response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode != HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) {
              apiCallLoop.break()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      Thread.sleep(200)
      EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        s"""######### Error while sending json with batchRunId: $batchRunId,
           | requestId: $requestId, error: >>> ${e} #########""".stripMargin
    }
  })
```

`
In the above UDF i am returning only strin, but if throw exception I get error
UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported

I tried changing this UDF to a normal function in which I can use `raise_error` function but with this approach the issue is I am not able to get the values of columns to variable to pass on to the API

`

```
val entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("data", json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("apiKey",  apiKey) **/////ERROR: NEED TO GET VALUE FROM COLUMN as string**
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("batchRunId", batchRunId)**/////ERROR: NEED TO GET VALUE FROM COLUMN as string**
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("mode", "NORMAL")
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("dataFormat", "JSON")
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("requestId", requestId)
      entityBuilder.addTextBody("dictionaryVersion", dictionaryVersion) **/////ERROR: NEED TO GET VALUE FROM COLUMN as string
**      entityBuilder.setCharset(Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()))
```

`
Please help

I tried the mentioned approaches but could not made it to work need an alternate approach

Comment: This code seems to be very blocking and very slow. Do you tried to avoid any Thread.sleep() and to close data source before operating with each row? And of course you don't need to create HttpClient each time